# Get value from FancySelect mootools

Tags: javascript, select, mootools

I was created a dropdown with mootools [FancySelect](http://mootools.net/forge/p/fancyselect).but i dont know how to get its value  to a variable when the value is changed.

**HTML**

```
   <select name="fruits" id="fruits">
     <option value="1" data-image="http://www.lorenzostanco.com/lab/demos/FancySelect/Graphics/Fruits/Apple.png">Apple</option>
     <option value="2" data-image="http://www.lorenzostanco.com/lab/demos/FancySelect/Graphics/Fruits/Banana.png">Banana</option>
   </select>
```

**Javascript**

```
        var $$=document.id;
        $$('fruits').fancySelect();
```

I try to get the value with jQuery.as follows

```
  $('#fruits').change(function(){
         alert($this).val())
  });
```

But it is fire an error,element is undefined.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shijin/ZA6df/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fancySelect that Lorenzo did [**has a option**](https://github.com/lorenzos/FancySelect#docs) for `legacyEvents`.
Turning that *on* fixes your problem.

Try this:

```
var $i = document.id;
$i('fruits').fancySelect({legacyEvents: true}); // note here i added {legacyEvents: true}
$i('fruits').addEvent('change', function () {
    alert(this.get('value'));
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GzbW3/)

**Note:** Don't do `var $$=document.id;` you are overriding a [**mootools method**](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Window%3adollars) which is `$$`. You can do `$i` istead.

Comment: Thanks,Its working fine for me,This is the first time i am working with mootools.....

Comment: @shin, Happy I could help. Welcome to MooTools!